# XMLPullParser checking for specific Child node

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

I have a XML like this:

```
<node_a>
    <node_b>
        <required/>
        <random_node1/>
    </node_b>
    <node_c>
        <required/>
    </node_c>
    <node_d>
        <random_node2/>
    </node_d>
</node_a>
```

and trying to parse it using [XMLPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)

I want to iterate through the XML and add all the node names that have the child . In this example i my result list should have node_b and node_c.

The problem i face is if i do a `parser.next()` then the pointer moves ahead and it is impossible for me get back and iterate through them again. There is no api to check for all child nodes.

What will be the best approach to go with.

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?  Please let me know if my answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
XmlPullParser paser = Xml.newPullParser();
... other init that you might need ...

parser.next(); // get first token

// In general, you'll need to add error checking such as this:  
if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
  ...error...
String parentName = parser.getName(); // this will be "node_a"

parser.next(); // done with first token; fetch next
while (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
{
  String childName = parser.getName(); // will be "node_b" first time through loop

  // get nested attributes - e.g. "required"
  parser.next();
  while (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
  {
    String nestedAttribute = parser.getName();
    ... do something with nestedAttribute ...

    parser.next();
  }
  if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
    ...error...

  parser.next(); // consume END_TAG for nested attributes
}
if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
  ...error...

// make sure we're at end of file
parser.next(); // consume END_TAG for node_a
if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullPaarser.END_DOCUMENT)
  ...error...
```